# System Database Migration and Security - Log Shipping or DB Mirroring

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, security, log-shipping, logins

I've setup log shipping between two servers (they used to be mirrored).

What is the simplest or most efficient way to mirror the system databases between the primary and secondary?

- Is it just a matter of backing these databases on the Primary and then restoring them on the Secondary?

Further, does anyone know of a TSQL script or a (free) program that'll script all logins from the primary server?

Comment: Is this a one time thing or do you need to keep them in sync? For the logins, try this script from Robert Davis. http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/transferring-logins-to-a-database-mirror

Comment: I'll check out the script, thank you!  The system database migration might happen more than once depending on what management decides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System databases cannot be mirrored or logshipping.

The best way is to script and sync up  desired objects e.g. logins, jobs, etc.

The best tool that I have used so far for migrating databases, jobs, agent schedules, operators, logins, etc is [powershell based dbatools.io](https://dbatools.io)

Comment: I should've mentioned that I realized that you can't log ship or mirror system databases.  It was a direct question of how to script them, if you will, and you answered that with your link.  Thank you, Kin!